# Nose tests for django app in pycharm

Tags: django, pycharm, nose

I'm working on a django package created using cookiecutter from [this repository](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-djangopackage).  It uses nose tests, with a script (`runtests.py`) that generates settings on the fly.  This works brilliantly.  I'd like to fully integrate these tests into PyCharm's test runner.  I can point the Nose test plugin at this script, and it executes and gets the correct test feedback, but in a way that it can't usefully identify which tests are failing when a test fails.  My project is on github [here](https://github.com/nebulans/django-permatrix).

Any hints on how to integrate the two nicely?

Comment: Install nose, set up pycharm settings to run nose tests by giving it a working directory